# What does it mean when the directory stucture in a URN contains the domain name for a website?

Tags: dns, url, dynamic-dns, domain-name

I'm looking at a section of a website with the following URN/directory structure:

http://www.domainNameA.net/site/www.domainNameA.net/files/dynamically%generated%URN_539.docx

Why does the site have the domain name listed again in the URN? What is this likely to indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can of course mean anything. It’s up to the owner how URLs are structured and what they contain. I could offer a picture under `http://example.com/http://google.com/http://wikipedia.org/picture.png`, where everything after my host (`http://example.com`) is part of the URL path ("google.com" and "wikipedia.org" are not interpreted as host names; [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36040349/1591669)).

One case where the URL design from your example can often be seen is in multi-site [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). Instead of installing a separate CMS for each website, you install only one CMS that manages all your sites. The files that are specific to one site will be placed in a folder that is named after that site’s domain name.

A possible case:

- the folder `/site/` contains one folder for each website
- the folder `/site/foo.example.com/` contains all files specific to the website `http://foo.example.com/`
- the folder `/site/bar.example.org/` contains all files specific to the website `http://bar.example.org/`

Now let’s say you are on `http://foo.example.com/` and you want to link to a picture that is in the folder `/site/foo.example.com/files/`. Without [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), the URL would be `http://foo.example.com/site/foo.example.com/files/picture.png`.

(All this has nothing to do with [URNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name); a URN is a URI that uses the `urn` URI scheme, instead of, e.g., `http`, `mailto`, `ftp`, etc.)

Comment: Multi-site CMS....... Extremely useful info and seems very likely in this case, thank you. I thought URN was just the name of the resource that appears in the address bar :/.